# How to set value for optionsCaption in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

How do I set a value for optionsCaption in knockoutjs?  For example in my application I have one select box:

```
<select name="item" id="item" class="input-fo" multiple="multiple" data-bind="
                                    options         : categories,
                                    optionsValue    : '_id',
                                    optionsCaption   :'Select All',
                                    optionsText     : 'name',
                                    selectedOptions : $data['item'],
                                    select2         : {}
                                ">
</select>
```

On top of the options, I set the optionsCaption as 'Select all'.  How can i set value for "select all" option when the page loads?  Can anyone please give me an idea for how to do this?

Answer (score 9):

You could just bind `optionsCaption` to any observable property of your view model and set it to `null` if you want to hide default combobox element.

Here is the example (you could try [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dimaka/7kuwy/) as well):

HTML:

```
Options caption: 
<input data-bind="value: defaultCaption" />
Use or not:<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: defaultCaptionEnabled" />

<select data-bind="
        value: selected, 
        options: items, 
        optionsText: 'title', 
        optionsValue: 'key', 
        optionsCaption: dynamicOptionsCaption()">
</select>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = function() {

    var self = this;

    self.selected = ko.observable('');
    self.defaultCaption = ko.observable('Select ...');
    self.defaultCaptionEnabled = ko.observable(true);

    self.items = ko.observableArray(
        [
            {key: 'KEY1', title: 'One'},
            {key: 'KEY2', title: 'Two'},
            {key: 'KEY3', title: 'Three'},
            {key: 'KEY4', title: 'Four'},
        ]
    );

    self.dynamicOptionsCaption = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.defaultCaptionEnabled() 
            ? self.defaultCaption()
            : null;
    });   
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like "Select All" to have a value then don't use the optionsCaption binding.  Instead just add an item of "Select All" as the first element of your array "MyDataSet" with an id property equal to the value you want for "Select All".

Comment: thanks for your reply but i get categories from database how can i add?

Comment: One way might be to use the unshift() function which adds an element to the beginning of an array.  It would look something like this: categories.unshift({id:'something', name:'Select All'});

Answer (score 1):

I do this in ASP.Net MVC by creating a global variable at the bottom of the page that I set with Razor.  I like to name the global variable after the page, but this is a personal preference.

For example:

```
var MyPage = window.MyPage || {};
MyPage.Terms = {
    SelectAllText: '@Model.Terms.SelectAllText'
};
```

You can then access the page global variable from your KO model.

```
(function (MyPage) {

    var Model = function() {
        this.terms = {
            selectAll: MyPage.Terms.SelectAll
        };
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new Model());

}(window.MyPage = window.MyPage || {}));
```

Then in your page markup just access the terms property.

```
<select name="item" id="item" class="input-fo" multiple="multiple" data-bind="
                                options         : categories,
                                optionsValue    : '_id',
                                optionsCaption  : terms.selectAll,
                                optionsText     : 'name',
                                selectedOptions : $data['item'],
                                select2         : {}
                            ">
```

This allows me to set a JavaScript variable using a server side model.  I mainly do this for internationalization.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get mine to work:

HTML:

```
  <select data-bind="options: MyDataSet, optionsText: 'MyOptionsText', optionsCaption: 'Select All', value: SelectedItem" ></select>
```

My ViewModel:

```
 var MyDataViewModel = {
        MyDataSet: ko.observableArray(),
        SelectedItem: ko.observable()
      }
```

My Ajax To populate Array:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/URLToYourMethod/GetJobTypes",
        data: {},
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "JSON",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (Result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < Result.d.length; i++) {
                element = Result.d[i];
                MyDataViewModel.MyDataSet.push({ MyID: element.MyID, MyOptionsText: element.MyOptionsText});
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

And that is about it.

Comment: hi  Jacques Bronkhorst thanks for your  reply i got one idead for dothis using java script  <script>

 
$('#base').change(function(){
    var selecteItem=$("#item option:selected");
     if(selecteItem.text() == 'Select All'){
      selecteItem.val('select_all');
     } 
 });
</script> it's working fine but in that when i select select all in my select option only but i need set default it means when page load sorry for my English.

Comment: @gow.java Is this perhaps what you are lokking for? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html This allows you to bind multiple objects with the select binding